# Stop enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock: from calling my block with nil values

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring, core-text

I'm calling the following selector on an existing `NSAttributedString` with no `kCTFontAttributeName` ranges:

```
[attributedString enumerateAttribute:(NSString *) kCTFontAttributeName
                             inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length])
                             options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired
                          usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Attribute: %@, %@", value, NSStringFromRange(range));
}];
```

and I get the output below, but I would expect to get no output. Suggestions?

```
Attribute: (null), {0, 27}
Attribute: (null), {27, 1}
Attribute: (null), {28, 1}
Attribute: (null), {29, 1}
Attribute: (null), {30, 1}
```

Comment: What happens, when you pass `0` as the options-parameter? The wording in the documentation for `...LongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired` is somewhat suspect...

Comment: I still get nulls, just fewer of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer? `-enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:` doesn't do what you (or I, originally) thought it does.

From the name, you might assume it *only* enumerates over ranges of the receiver that contain the given attribute. This is not the case. It *always* enumerates over the *entire* string. It calls the block for *each* run it encounters. The `value` passed into the block is set to the value the given attribute for that run. If the current run doesn't contain the given attribute, it passes `nil` for `value`.

Thus, for a string that does not contain the given attribute, it will still fire the block, but the `value` will always be `nil`. For a string that that is completely covered by the the given attribute (with the same value), you would expect the block to fire once with `value` being equal to that attribute's value in the string. For a string that is partially covered by the given attribute, you would expect the block to fire multiple times, sometimes with a `value` of `nil`, and sometimes with a `value` equal to that of the attribute.

Hope that helps. It took me a while to look at it from the correct direction, also.

Comment: Can you please link to documentation or an email from someone from Apple that outlines this?  I agree that this is the behavior I experience, but I'm mostly looking for an official reason.

Comment: I don't think there is a "reason", per se. The canonical documentation states, simply, "Executes the Block for the specified attribute run in the specified range." This is consistent with both our expected behavior and the *actual* behavior I outline above. If you're looking for something a little more concrete, you should really file a documentation bug with Apple.

Comment: I agree that the documentation is ambiguous, but usually the Apple Engineer on the mailing list is quick to respond. Text from an email from him would be great.

Comment: It only took me 7 years to give up on my documentation radar.

Comment: That is one badly named **and** documented method. I keep getting bitten by this despite having read this answer several times. @HeathBordersdo you by any chance have the radar # so I could dupe?